# Remove text from string not working

Tags: javascript

I have this string: `"gss_save,cls,x_value"`. I want to convert it to `"x_value"`. I tried this:

```
//var cls is "gss_save,cls,x_value";
var fnl = cls.replace('gss_save,cls,','');
console.log(fnl);
```

As suggested by other answers in this site, but I get: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` in line `var fnl = cls.replace('gss_save,cls,','');`. Expecting to get `"x_value"`.

Comment: That works fine for me. Can you show more code? http://jsfiddle.net/BloodyKnuckles/n9fjhLaj/

Comment: Sorry it was an array I used toString and it worked, thank you anyway

Answer (score 1):

Another way is

```js
var fnl = cls.split(',');
fnl= fnl[fnl.length-1]
console.log(fnl);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a 'regex pattern' which looks like **/.../** without quotation marks!

**string.replace(pattern, replacement)**

Example:

```
var str = "gss_save,cls,x_value";
var pattern = /gss_save,cls,/;
var res = str.replace(pattern, "");
```